# How to place a number into a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to create the following function

```
Left_padded(n, width)
```

That returns, for example:

```
Left_padded(6, 4):
'   6' #number 6 into a 4 digits space
```

```
Left_padded(54, 5)
'   54' #number 54 into a 5 digits space
```

Comment: `def left_padded(n, w): return '{}'.format(n).rjust(w)`

Comment: You can already do this trivially with, e.g., `f'{6: 4}'`. Are you looking to implement something from scratch, for an assignment? If so, show us what you've tried and whee you're stuck.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Why not just put the rjust into the format spec?

Comment: @abarnert I'm not aware of a way of inserting variables for the width in the format spec.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If you want it to be a variable, you just use another pair of braces: `'{:>{}}'.format(6, 4)`. Of course it quickly gets a bit unclear if you do it that way (looks more like an emoticon than Python code), but with names it's readable: `'{n:>{w}}'.format(n=n, w=w)` or, better, `f'{n:>{w}}'`, or, best of all, `f'{num:>{width}}'` with meaningful variable names.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ And if you're _not_ using a format spec beyond just `'{}'`, why use one at all, instead of just `format(n)` or `str(n)`?

Comment: @abarnert Like I said... learning every day... especially from your answers and comments (-;

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust):

```
>>> def Left_padded(n, width):
...     return str(n).rjust(width)
>>> Left_padded(54, 5)
'   54'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to put the number next to another string, you can also use [`%`](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) formatting to achieve the same result:

```
>>> w1 = "your number is:"
>>> num = 20
>>> line = '%s%10s' % (w1, num)
>>> print(line)
'your number is:        20'
```

Comment: But why would you want to?